# Mailchimp landing page fail to index on Google Search Console because blocked by robots.tx

Tags: indexing, mailchimp, google-search-console

A mailchimp landing page with a custom subdomain is failing to index on Google Search Console because it's being blocked by robots.txt.

The domain is authenticated on Mailchimp and the landing page subdomain is verified on Mailchimp. SSL is working fine. Google Search Console is able to index other subdomains using other services - just not the Mailchimp landing page. I didn't see anywhere within the Mailchimp portal where the robots.txt file can be modified.

I was expecting Google Search Console to queue up the landing page for indexing. However, I received an alert: Index Request Rejected. Drilling into the alert: Crawl was not allowed because it's blocked by robots.txt.